# Gradle: using tasks from other files

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi-project gradle setup. As one would imagine, some projects need to use the same custom tasks. I looked around for a way to use tasks located in another build.gradle file, to avoid code reproduction, but couldn't find any info. 
Is there a way to do this? If not, is there an elegant workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The easiest way would be to define it in the root project with `subprojects { ... }`. You also can write it in a separate file and add it with `apply from: yourfile.gradle`.

If you want a more specific answer, you have to give more information about your projects and the task.

Comment: The thing is, while it's a multi-project setup, I'd still want to be able to build each project (and his dependencies) separately (should have mentioned it to begin now that I think about it). I was using the `subprojects{...}` so far, but was looking for something like the `apply from: ` option you mentioned. Thanks!